# Using relationship index on gremlin is relatively slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher, gremlin

In Neo4j, I have a relationship index 'index_e_ASSOC_sMETHdGEXP' containing about 180000 edges, all with an attribute 'property'. I want to do a simple query that lists 200 edges from the index, at this point regardless of the property value (later do a query like fetch the same attribute values for the 200 first edge out vertices where the edge property <= 0.01), and fetch a few attribute values from the out node:

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis();
t = new Table(); g.idx('index_e_ASSOC_sMETHdGEXP')[[property: Neo4jTokens.QUERY_HEADER + "*"]][0..200].outV().id.as('nodeId').back(1).alias.as("alias").back(1).chr.as('chr').table(t,["nodeId","alias","chr"]).iterate();
System.currentTimeMillis() - time
```

**=713ms**

Getting the 200 first edges from the index takes **262ms**:

```
time = System.currentTimeMillis();
g.idx('index_e_ASSOC_sMETHdGEXP')[[property: Neo4jTokens.QUERY_HEADER + "*"]][0..200];
System.currentTimeMillis() - time
```

Why is the first query completed so slowly? It shouldn't take this long to get 200 edges from a "predetermined list" and fetch a few attribute values from every output node. I'm a complete newbie when it comes to Cypher and Gremlin, so is there a faster way to do this query, either in Cypher or Gremlin?

Edit: ran the query (1) 23 times:

```
==> 1124
==> 983
==> 951
==> 864
==> 1175
==> 1189
==> 889
==> 917
==> 822
==> 872
==> 795
==> 736
==> 840
==> 1189
==> 723
==> 756
==> 691
==> 44609
==> 644
==> 640
==> 1110
==> 1007
==> 819
```

Edit2: I have since re-imported the database with the following configuration:

```
dump_configuration=true
cache_type=gcr
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=4G
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=200M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory=1G
neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory=1G
relationship_cache_array_fraction=8
node_cache_array_fraction=8
node_cache_size=3G
relationship_cache_size=6G
```

Now the query(1) actually takes longer: **23849 ms**. It's starting to look like a cache issue.

Interesting snippets of the db log:

```
2012-07-06 10:51:49,149 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: System memory information:
2012-07-06 10:51:49,152 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Total Physical memory: 26,37 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,152 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Free Physical memory: 11,99 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,153 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Committed virtual memory: 16,43 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,153 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Total swap space: 27,00 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,153 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Free swap space: 26,96 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,154 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: JVM memory information:
2012-07-06 10:51:49,154 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Free  memory: 1,84 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,154 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Total memory: 1,87 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,154 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Max   memory: 13,33 GB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,588 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: Storage files:
2012-07-06 10:51:49,589 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: messages.log: 304,72 kB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,589 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.propertystore.db.index: 1,02 kB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,589 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.propertystore.db: 401,18 MB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,590 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.relationshipstore.db.id: 9,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,590 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: index.db: 1,42 kB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,590 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: tm_tx_log.1: 0,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,590 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names.id: 9,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,591 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.propertystore.db.id: 9,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,591 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.nodestore.db: 478,88 kB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,591 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: nioneo_logical.log.active: 4,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,591 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.nodestore.db.id: 9,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,591 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.propertystore.db.strings.id: 9,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,592 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.id: 9,00 B
2012-07-06 10:51:49,592 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.propertystore.db.strings: 34,15 MB
2012-07-06 10:51:49,592 DEBUG [neo4j.diagnostics]: neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.id: 9,00 B
2012-07-06 10:53:01,486 INFO  [neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 14826ms [total block time: 14.826s]
2012-07-06 10:54:24,019 INFO  [neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 875ms [total block time: 15.701s]
2012-07-06 10:55:25,441 INFO  [neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 559ms [total block time: 16.26s]
2012-07-06 11:00:16,962 INFO  [neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 775ms [total block time: 17.035s]
```

JVM parameters include

```
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-Xms2000m,
-Xmx15360m
```

It seems that the garbage collector interferes with the execution, why is that? With the JVM params I'm telling to the server instance to use max amount of ~15GB memory which should be plenty.

Edit4: Doing query(1) adds the following to the log:

```
2012-07-06 11:40:31,973 INFO  [neo4j]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 23745ms [total block time: 23.745s]
2012-07-06 11:40:33,961 INFO  [neo4j]: RelationshipCache array size: 17895751 purge count: 0 size is: 0b, 100.0% misses, NaN% collisions (0).
2012-07-06 11:40:33,966 INFO  [neo4j]: NodeCache array size: 17895751 purge count: 0 size is: 0b, 100.0% misses, NaN% collisions (0).
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the query multiple times, so you are operating on a warm graph and index?

Comment: Ran 23 times and as you can see, it varies quite much. Mostly for the worse.